# How to share classes between .NET projects without using a library?

Tags: .net, code-sharing

I have two projects - one is a test one, other is the final version. I know there is a possibility to put shared code into a library, but I want that compiled result will be a single file, without any additional DLLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "link" a code file between two or more projects. Just Right click your project, choose `Add -> Existing item`, and then click the down arrow next to the Add button:

In my experience linking is simpler than creating a library. Linked code results in a single executable with a single version.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) which will merge number of .Net assemblies to a single assembly.

Answer (score 2):

You should usually be able to add the same source code file to more than one project. In C#, for example, projects can contain links to files that are stored in other locations and that will be included in the compilation like any other files.

- In Visual Studio 2012, for example, the [selected answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767269/add-existing-item-in-visual-studio-is-it-possible-to-make-add-as-link-defau) points out that you can drag files into a project while pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to create a link.
- [This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234/en-us) points out that a respective option is found in the *Open file* dialog when adding an existing file in some versions of Visual Studio.
- In SharpDevelop 4, you can use *Add* -> *Existing item* from the project (or a project folder's) context menu to select an existing file to add to the project; if that file is outside of the folder hierarchy of your project; SharpDevelop will ask you whether you want to copy the file or just create a link to it.